# Find the value of Δx for which the value of Δy/Δx is within 0.1 units of slope.

Tags: derivatives, inequality, slope

Here is the link for the problem that I am trying to solve:

https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-01sc-single-variable-calculus-fall-2010/1.-differentiation/part-a-definition-and-basic-rules/session-1-introduction-to-derivatives/

The problem is 1c in the pdf:

https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-01sc-single-variable-calculus-fall-2010/1.-differentiation/part-a-definition-and-basic-rules/session-1-introduction-to-derivatives/MIT18_01SCF10_ex01sol.pdf

The final solution is next:

$$-0.08 \le \Delta x \le 0.10$$

As I understand this is the formula for this problem where m is the slope:

$$-0.1m \le  \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}  \le 0.1m$$

But I can't understand why the numbers on each end are different. Appreciate any help.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: [Here's what I see.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owBOV.jpg) Please use MathJax. If you're unsure of what code to use for a symbol, try Detexify.

Comment: Please try now.

Comment: That's better. Thank you.